# resizing and center image in markdown

Tags: css, markdown

I am trying to resize the image and center it in markdown by using

`![flower](/image/flower.png){: .center-image, height="300px", width="150px"}`

Is it possible to use more than one css inside `{ ... }`? Thanks

Comment: Which flavour / MD parser are you using? That's not regular markdown (and it's not CSS inside either).

Comment: Do you perhaps mean: "... more than one **class**"? if so, have you tried it? What was the result? How does that differ from the expected result?

Comment: @BenM I use kramdown and it's CSS inside.

Comment: @Waylan I tried again and now it works. I made a mistake using commas inside.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple answer is yes. But make sure you are using supported attributes.

The language syntax you are using is from [Kramdown](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/), which is the Markdown engine used by GitHub among others. Specifically it specifies a [Span Inline](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#span-ials)
syntax. The Kramdown syntax docs are [here](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html).